# Winforms DataBinding

Tags: winforms, data-binding

There's a text box and some view model with detail

```
public class Detail { public string Value {get;set;}}

public class SomeVM
{
     public Detail {get;set;}
}
```

Trying to bind to textbox with this code:

```
textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", new SomeVm (), "Detail.Value");
```

But it says "there's no property to bind". Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
public string Value 
{
  get
  {
      return _someVm.Value;
  }
  set
  {
      _someVm.Value=value;
  }
} 
private readonly SomeVM _someVM=new SomeVM();
 ...
textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", _someVm, "Value");
```